# AWS ECS environment variable not available [Python]

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS with a Python Framework and in my task definition i have the option to add environment variables that will be available to the service(cluster).

Here is where i added the env variables:
[image]

When i then try to print all the env variables in my service i do not get access to these variables and i am not sure why. Here i printed all my env using environ:

```
for a in os.environ:
    print('Var: ', a, 'Value: ', os.getenv(a))
print("all done")
```

Result:
[image]

**DB_PORT** or **APP_KEY** is not available in my service or python-code.

Comment: Is it possible that your python script is not the container ENTRYPOINT but it is maybe triggered by something else? I ran into a similar issue, where the environment variables are not necessarily passed to subshells.

Comment: The Python is only running a CRON job with crontab and nothing else (no webservice). Could it be that the envs is not available in cron jobs? if so, how would i access it then?

Comment: I added some more info to the question (crontab code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it seems to me that the full environment is passed only to the PID 1 (init process, which in a container should be CMD/ENTRYPOINT command). Cron is not that process so you cannot assume it sees the same environment.

What I did may not be the best solution, it is rather a hack, but it works.

The environment of a process is available in `/proc/<pid>/environ`, so in this case `/proc/1/environ`. I grab it from there and I store it in a file for a future use:

```
for I in `cat /proc/1/environ  | strings`; do echo "export $I"; done > /src/.profile
```

and then I just `source /src/.profile` in my scripts (the cron job in your case).

If you need AWS credentials, you may also need access to `ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4` environment variable and that one will be also there.

Comment: Should i add this code in the cronhelper.sh before the cd command? (sorry for noob question. new to linux and docker).

Comment: yes, that should work, you need both the for and the source command. Let you give it a try and if it works you may make with more pretty later.

Comment: /home/local/cronhelper.sh: source: not found.  Changed to bash on top of cronhelper.sh, will see if that works

Comment: you may not have the /src/ folder, of course, you have to adjust to your configuration.

Comment: Booom! it worked in AWS now. Thanks @petrch. This caused me a headache today. Looks like this is solved now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: good to hear that, perfect!